# How to change the cancel icon in Xamarin Forms Shell SearchHandler

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms Shell app where I have implemented the Shell SearchHandler. The cancel button shows a book image.

[image]

This only occurs on iOS - on Android, there is no cancel button.

My xaml looks like this:

```
<Shell.SearchHandler>
    <controls:RouteSearchHandler
        x:Name="RouteSearch"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        ClearPlaceholderCommand="{Binding ClearSearch}"
        ClearPlaceholderIcon="{StaticResource Cancel}"
        DisplayMemberName="Street1"
        SearchBoxVisibility="{Binding TopSearchVisibility, Converter={StaticResource visibleConvert}}"
        ShowsResults="True" />
</Shell.SearchHandler>
```

How do I change the cancel icon from a book to another fonticon or image?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a potential issue , the team set a default(book) icon on **Clear button**.

#### Workaround

You can prepare a small/transparent image and place it in Resources folder in iOS project , and set `ClearPlaceholderIcon` with it, then the problem should be solved .

And Feel free to file the feature request on github :https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues.

Comment: No - I get the clear icon fine. I want to change the cancel icon. Currently displays a book image

Comment: Do you set something in `RouteSearchHandler` code behind ?  There is not any `cancel icon` on my side .

Comment: No. Just used the boiler plate from the sample. I have an OnQueryChanged an OnItemSelected - nothing else.

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a basic, reproducible project to test ? You can upload to github and attach the link here .

Comment: This is a simple File | New | Tabbed project from VS Mac 2019. I only partially implemented the SearchHandler work as it demonstrates my question. NOTE: the "book" icon for cancel ONLY shows up on iOS. https://github.com/420tech/TestSB

Comment: Check my update .